# How to set a custom sound in react-native-push-notifications remotely

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, remote-notifications, react-native-push-notification

I have configured remote notifications, and everything is working as expected. Now I want to set a custom sound to my remote notifications. I have tried many ways but these are not working. 
I am using **react-native-push-notification** and **react-native-firebase**.

I have placed a **custom sound** file in `android/app/src/main/res/raw/sound.mp3`.

I have also tried `soundName:"sound.mp3"` 
I appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks. :)
Below is the sample Code:

`````
PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: async function(token) {

      },
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log(notification);
      },
      senderID: 'xxxx',
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },
      playSound: true,
      soundName: 'sound.mp3',
      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  }````
`````

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Rajan Server side or the client-side?

Comment: Client side code.

Comment: Please have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

For android you must provide a channel id with **channelId: "your-channel-id"**, if the channel doesn't exist the notification might not be triggered.

**NOTE: Without channel, notifications might not work**

```
  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: "channel-id", // (required)
      channelName: "My channel", // (required)
      soundName: "sound.mp3",
      importance: 4,
      vibrate: true,
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
```

In the soundName option you put your custom sound name for this channel (for default sound, use 'default'), and use the channel Id when sending a notification